# Chrome can't connect to example.com server

Tags: linux, centos, php

How can I get all my php files run on a Linux server? I copied all PHP files to my Linux server under `/www` and I did change config settings like the following. Also I created an error log file under `/logs`.

But when I run `mytest.example.com` in browser, it is not working and the page shows:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not find mytest.example.com

I think I need to change or add something.

I use Putty to access the Centos and use WinSCP as FTP.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mytest.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/allphpfile/
ErrorLog logs/my_test_error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you tried putting a phpinfo file? added php modules in http.conf? are you getting the default apache web page?

Comment: Do `nslookup mytest.example.com` in command line. Does that show your IP address? Do you have a DNS server set up for that (I don't think you're the owner of example.com domain, right)? lol

Comment: Also make sure your files are in `/var/www` and not `/www` – there's no reason to put them into a folder at the root level of your file system.

Comment: @slhck Actually, these days something like [/srv/www](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM) might be a more appropriate place.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling True, good to know, but if the OP is using a default LAMP install, I guess `/var/www` should do.

Answer (score 1):

You can not connect to a service under *example.com* unless you are the owner of that domain. You need three things to host PHP content;

1. PHP enabled web server (e.g Apache).
2. PHP modules for that server.
3. A computer (or VM) with a public IP address.

Technically speaking, you don't need any of that to "run a PHP file". You can install the interpreter using the package manager and invoke it on a file:

```
php /home/moo/somescript.php
```

---

Another user suggested that it is actually possible to use the example domain if it is configured locally. To enable the local machine to resolve an arbitrary domain, you can associate that arbitrary domain with an arbitrary IP address in /etc/hosts like so:

/etc/hosts:

```
 # local
 10.3.0.1        monger.lan      mon.lan monger   mon   ruter
 10.3.0.3        tryggve.lan     try.lan tryggve  try
 # remote
 xx.zz.yy.185  caracal
 xx.zz.yy.184  gaupe
 xx.zz.yy.175  login.pvv.org pvv
 # example
 127.0.0.1     mytest.example.org
```

(xx.zz.yy must be actual numbers)

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:** configure LAMP server in centos followed by few step, reference url for configuration https://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6 and also install phpmyadmin for database management refrence url https://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6

Comment: Instead of just posting links to complete LAMP configuration tutorials, you should attempt to address the specific issue the OP has, namely not being able to connect to `example.com` – for obvious reasons.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install php package through rpm or yum.
2. Then first we need to know what kind of hosting user require(dedicated hosting or virtual hosting)
3. Install mysql package on server
4. make changes in httpd>conf>httpd.conf file if you wants to get any change regarding the apache service port No and all that
5. To provide the virtual hosting through a single service & singla IP. Kindly refer below

   DocumentRoot /var/www/.html
   ServerName example.com
6. start httpd service
   service httpd start
7. Now try to host any of website by providing the ip of apache installed system at DNS for or rev files.
8. Enjoy the day